# Error: Java: file does not exist. How to change where compiler is looking for the file?

Tags: java, file, path

When I run this project, which I created using the intellij IDE, I am getting this error:

> Error:java:file:C:\C:\Users\SlinkyMation\Documents\Java_Stuff\Java_Library\GUI_Stuff\House\out\production\House: does not exist

Clearly, the problem lies in the "C:\C:" part, but I am not sure how to fix the file path. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you building the path to this file (please edit your question to include that code), and is the path correct otherwise?

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I got it figured out. I had to check the build path. I did not know what was going wrong thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had to change my build path.